# How to handle the exception from a library that use a threading.timer?

Tags: c#

I have a libray that use a timer, and I would like to throw and exception if there is some error, but I want that the main application that use this library handle this exception, because it could do few things, for example send and email, write a log file or write a message in cosole, I think that it is better that this it is made by the main application instead of the library.

So I have this code:

My class in the library:

```
MyclassLibrary
{
    Timer _timer;

    public MyclassLibrary()
    {
        //I create the timer
        _timer = new Timer(MyHandler, null, 0, 1000);
    }

    private void MyHandler(object paramObject)
    {
        try
        {
            //do something
        }
        cath(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MyCustomException();
        }
    }
}
```

My main application

```
MyMain
{
    MyClassLibrary _myClass;

    public MyMain()
    {
        _myClass = new MyClassLibrary;
    }
}
```

At this point, I don't know how to catch the exception from the library in may main application, because there is no any method that catch it.

I could catch the exception in the constructor, when I instantiate _myClass, that it starts to run, but if in some iteration of the timer, that will throw an exception, where could I catch and handle this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Create an event on the class in your library that is raised on exceptions, and that you can write the handler for in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never be able to handle the exception caught within `MyHandler` from the calling class.

One way to code this is to expose an `Error` event from your class and subscribe to that event in calling code:

```
public class MyClassLibrary
{
    Timer _timer;

    public MyClassLibrary()
    {
        //I create the timer
        _timer = new Timer(MyHandler, null, 0, 1000);
    }
    
    public event EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> Error;
    
    protected void OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        if(Error != null)
            Error(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex));
    }

    private void MyHandler(object paramObject)
    {
        try
        {
           // Do something
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            OnError(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Exception Exception {get; }
    
    public ErrorEventArgs(Exception ex)
    {
        this.Exception = ex;
    }
}
```

And then calling code becomes something like:

```
var _myClass = new MyClassLibrary();
_myClass.Error += (sender,ea) => Console.WriteLine(ea.Exception);
```

A word of warning though; you might prefer to expose a `Start` method which actually starts the timer, allowing you time to register your event so the code becomes more like:

```
 var _myClass = new MyClassLibrary();
_myClass.Error += (sender,ea) => Console.WriteLine(ea.Exception);
_myClass.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution, and also for the advise to expose a start method.